# amCharts Live Stock with draw option

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I am using amChart v5 for live stock data from this example
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/live-stock-data/

I want to a solution when user will click on any external button a new tooltip of will appear on graph which will be on fixed position and after a duration a result tooltip will apprear with an close icon. On close icon click both tooltip will be removed and there can be multiple pairs of tooltip on a graph as shown in below image
[image]

I found drawing tool of Callout option is the similar thing I am looking for

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/stock/toolbar/drawing-control/

This can generate a fixed position tooltip on graph as shown in image.[image] [image]

But there is one issue with this tool. I am not able to draw the callout programmatically. By clicking on graph I need to enter some text than tooltip will be generated. I am looking for the solution to do this programmatically.

Comment: You can serialize and restore any annotations programatically. More info: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/stock/serializing-indicators-annotations/